# Export Fabric Answers to Excel

Tags: crashlytics, crashlytics-android, crashlytics-beta

We have Twitter's Answers integrated in our apps.
We have custom events. I need to export somehow all the answers(user metrics) from their website to excel sheet or similar in order to analyze it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.
Download the needed event table as CSV and then you can convert it to Excel or whatever you need. Another topic is that the data is only for events per day and it is without the additional parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can export it from Fabric directly.

[image: sample]

Available for both [iOS](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/answers/export-data.html) and [Android](https://docs.fabric.io/android/answers/export-data.html)